# How do I write a basic contravariant functor definition in Python?

Tags: haskell, functor, python-3.6, contravariance

I've been trying to understand some of the abstract concepts in Haskell by translating them to Python, but I can't seem to figure out how to write a class that satisfies the axioms defining contravariant functor.

I think the following class captures the concept of a basic functor on 'non-iterable' types.

```
from typing import Any, Iterable
from types import FunctionType as Function
from abc import abstractmethod


class _FunctorBase:

    value: Any = None

    def __call__(self, value: Any) -> '_FunctorBase':
        """ Make the functor type callable """
        self.value = value
        return self

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.value})'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()

    def __eq__(self, other: '_FunctorBase') -> bool:
        return self.value == other.value

    def __ne__(self, other: '_FunctorBase') -> bool:
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    @abstractmethod
    def fmap(self, f: Function) -> '_FunctorBase':
        raise NotImplementedError


class FunctorWrapper(_FunctorBase):
    """ Just a basic wrapping functor for a non-iterable value """

    def fmap(self, f: Function) -> 'FunctorWrapper':
        return FunctorWrapper()(f(self.value))
```

I can show that these types satisfy the following axioms (at least, for specific lambda functions), as shown on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html),

```
fmap id  ==  id
fmap (f . g)  ==  fmap f . fmap g
```

as follows:

```
def id(x: Any) -> Any: return x


def test_functor() -> None:
    wrap = FunctorWrapper()(3)

    print(wrap.fmap(id))
    print(wrap.fmap(lambda x: x + 1))
    print(wrap.fmap(lambda x: x + 1).fmap(lambda x: x + 1))

    assert wrap.fmap(lambda x: x + 1).fmap(lambda y: y * 2) == \
           wrap.fmap(lambda z: (z + 1) * 2), \
        'Functor does not satisfy composition axiom'

    assert wrap.fmap(id) == wrap, 'Functor does not satisfy identity axiom'

    print('** Functor passes all axioms')

test_functor()

# FunctorWrapper(3)
# FunctorWrapper(4)
# FunctorWrapper(5)
# ** Functor passes all axioms
```

Or, if you'd prefer a type that can be 'mapped over' in a more explicit manner:

```
class FunctorIterableList(_FunctorBase):

    def fmap(self, f: Function) -> 'FunctorIterable':
        return FunctorIterableList()(list(map(f, self.value)))

# FunctorIterableList([1, 2, 3, 4])
# FunctorIterableList([2, 3, 4, 5])
# FunctorIterableList([3, 4, 5, 6])
# ** Functor passes all axioms
```

However, a contravariant functor must satisfy the reversal of composition,

```
contramap f . contramap g = contramap (g . f)
```

I don't know how to reverse function composition in Python in this manner; I've been thinking the solution might be to store the first action internally in the class definition, then, upon calling with a second, applying the second prior to the first ? There must be a way to satisfy this without storing that kind of information internally though.

Comment: Is `_FunctorBase` meant to be a base class for all Functors? If so, why is it callable? Most Functors don't behave like functions. And why does it have a value? Many Functors don't have at least 1 value, like lists (which can be empty),  `Maybe` (which can be `Nothing`), and `Proxy` (which never holds any value).

Comment: You won't be able to translate most Haskell concepts into Python because Python's type system is simply too weak to support most things. For example, your `fmap` is simply a function with the type `(FunctorBase,PythonValue -> PythonValue) -> FunctorBase`. This doesn't really encode what a functor is, namely `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: @Cirdec good points. I'll try to rewrite that definition. I wrote it as more of a helper-like base class. I'll simply remove those lines.

Comment: @Lazersmoke I've found that in practice to be too true, why I'm trying to figure out Haskell or Scala, which have far more powerful type systems.

Comment: @bjd2385 If you want to learn a functional language like Haskell, I encourage you to abandon trying to learn it by analogy to imperative languages, and dive into it as learning a new skill. If functional and imperative languages were sufficiently the same there'd be little value to gain learning the other method. Good places to start are [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) or any of the other resources listed on the [Haskell tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info).

Comment: @Circdec encouragement noted, and I'm reading _Real World Haskell_ as well.